# /sbin/getty process causing 100% CPU utilization

Tags: server, upstart, ruby

I have an instance of `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-25-virtual i686)` running as a KVM-VM on a host-machine that runs one more VM beside it.

I deploy a Ruby on Rails application using the Capistrano deployment-gem.

However, if I deploy twice in a row in a short time, the CPU usage jumps to 100% because of the `/sbin/getty` process.

How can this be?

I believe getty is a rather simple program that passes a login-name from a terminal to a login-process.

Also: In my Capfile (Capistrano configuration file) I am running certain commands after the Rails application is deployed including a call to `sudo /sbin/restart <APPNAME>` which is an upstart task.

Could this be related somehow?

I can always kill the getty process and the problem is gone until the next deployment, but I would rather understand and fix the problem.

Any help is appreciated.
Attached is a screenshot of my problem.

[image: /sbin/getty causes 100% CPU load]

Comment: You can trace what the getty is doing with 'strace -f -p 18081' where 18081 is the pid of the misbehaving getty. If strace doesn't show anything, its likely a bug in getty.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue permanently?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I also encountered this issue on a `Ubuntu 12.10 Server` VPS.

But as I don't need any `tty` (because I'm connecting by `ssh`) I fixed it the **hard way**:

```
sudo rm /etc/init/tty*
sudo reboot
```

And it works pretty well! no more `getty` process stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging to `syslog`?

Is your `syslog` going to `tty1`?

If so, there's a good chance you have more than 38400bps worth of `syslog` and `getty` is blocking while it waits to dump data into its `tty`.

I'd check your `rsyslog` configuration - by default, Ubuntu logs some `syslog` output to `/dev/xconsole via /etc/rsyslogd.d/50-default.conf`.

Comment: If this is the case, how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

On one of my core I was getting 100% CPU utilization for `agetty` process on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. In my particular case I only used ssh connection for accessing server, therefore after investigating for a while I decided to remove it.

```
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service
sudo rm /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
```

Reboot is required. Solution was found at https://peteris.rocks/blog/can-you-kill-it/ . Before taking such option, be careful to check if you really do not need tty.